Elementor editor won't load unless SCRIPT_DEBUG = true
See title. I have tried many things already, including a complete reinstall of WordPress. Whenever I try to load the Elementor editor I get the following error:
VM4190:6 Uncaught TypeError: $e.components.get(...).utils.allowAddingWidgets is not a function
    at eval (eval at template (load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=underscore,jquery-core,jquery-migrate,backbone,wp-hooks,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-mouse,wp-api-request&ver=6.6.1:2:15198), <anonymous>:6:68)
    at e (load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=underscore,jquery-core,jquery-migrate,backbone,wp-hooks,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-mouse,wp-api-request&ver=6.6.1:2:15271)
    at Object.render (backbone.marionette.min.js?ver=2.4.5.e1:24:17797)
    at n._renderTemplate (backbone.marionette.min.js?ver=2.4.5.e1:24:23381)
    at n.render (backbone.marionette.min.js?ver=2.4.5.e1:24:23027)
    at Jn (load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=underscore,jquery-core,jquery-migrate,backbone,wp-hooks,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-mouse,wp-api-request&ver=6.6.1:2:7441)
    at n.<anonymous> (load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=underscore,jquery-core,jquery-migrate,backbone,wp-hooks,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-mouse,wp-api-request&ver=6.6.1:2:7755)
    at n.render (load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=underscore,jquery-core,jquery-migrate,backbone,wp-hooks,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-mouse,wp-api-request&ver=6.6.1:2:1065)
    at constructor._renderView (backbone.marionette.min.js?ver=2.4.5.e1:24:13219)
    at constructor.show (backbone.marionette.min.js?ver=2.4.5.e1:24:12223)
eval @ VM4190:6
e @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=underscore,jquery-core,jquery-migrate,backbone,wp-hooks,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-mouse,wp-api-request&ver=6.6.1:2
render @ backbone.marionette.min.js?ver=2.4.5.e1:24
_renderTemplate @ backbone.marionette.min.js?ver=2.4.5.e1:24
render @ backbone.marionette.min.js?ver=2.4.5.e1:24
Jn @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=underscore,jquery-core,jquery-migrate,backbone,wp-hooks,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-mouse,wp-api-request&ver=6.6.1:2
(anonymous) @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=underscore,jquery-core,jquery-migrate,backbone,wp-hooks,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-mouse,wp-api-request&ver=6.6.1:2
(anonymous) @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=underscore,jquery-core,jquery-migrate,backbone,wp-hooks,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-mouse,wp-api-request&ver=6.6.1:2
_renderView @ backbone.marionette.min.js?ver=2.4.5.e1:24
show @ backbone.marionette.min.js?ver=2.4.5.e1:24
showChildView @ backbone.marionette.min.js?ver=2.4.5.e1:25
onBeforeShow @ editor.min.js?ver=3.23.4:3
(anonymous) @ backbone.marionette.min.js?ver=2.4.5.e1:24
triggerMethod @ backbone.marionette.min.js?ver=2.4.5.e1:24
f.triggerMethodOn @ backbone.marionette.min.js?ver=2.4.5.e1:24
show @ backbone.marionette.min.js?ver=2.4.5.e1:24
constructor @ editor.min.js?ver=3.23.4:3
_buildRegionFromRegionClass @ backbone.marionette.min.js?ver=2.4.5.e1:24
buildRegion @ backbone.marionette.min.js?ver=2.4.5.e1:24
addRegion @ backbone.marionette.min.js?ver=2.4.5.e1:24
(anonymous) @ backbone.marionette.min.js?ver=2.4.5.e1:24
(anonymous) @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=underscore,jquery-core,jquery-migrate,backbone,wp-hooks,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-mouse,wp-api-request&ver=6.6.1:2
(anonymous) @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=underscore,jquery-core,jquery-migrate,backbone,wp-hooks,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-mouse,wp-api-request&ver=6.6.1:2
addRegions @ backbone.marionette.min.js?ver=2.4.5.e1:24
addRegions @ backbone.marionette.min.js?ver=2.4.5.e1:25
initPanel @ editor.min.js?ver=3.23.4:3
onFirstPreviewLoaded @ editor.min.js?ver=3.23.4:3
onPreviewLoaded @ editor.min.js?ver=3.23.4:3
onPreviewLoaded @ editor.min.js?ver=3.23.4:3
dispatch @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=underscore,jquery-core,jquery-migrate,backbone,wp-hooks,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-mouse,wp-api-request&ver=6.6.1:4
v.handle @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=underscore,jquery-core,jquery-migrate,backbone,wp-hooks,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-mouse,wp-api-request&ver=6.6.1:4
load
add @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=underscore,jquery-core,jquery-migrate,backbone,wp-hooks,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-mouse,wp-api-request&ver=6.6.1:4
(anonymous) @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=underscore,jquery-core,jquery-migrate,backbone,wp-hooks,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-mouse,wp-api-request&ver=6.6.1:7
e.<computed> @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=underscore,jquery-core,jquery-migrate,backbone,wp-hooks,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-mouse,wp-api-request&ver=6.6.1:7
(anonymous) @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=underscore,jquery-core,jquery-migrate,backbone,wp-hooks,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-mouse,wp-api-request&ver=6.6.1:4
each @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=underscore,jquery-core,jquery-migrate,backbone,wp-hooks,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-mouse,wp-api-request&ver=6.6.1:4
each @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=underscore,jquery-core,jquery-migrate,backbone,wp-hooks,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-mouse,wp-api-request&ver=6.6.1:4
Le @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=underscore,jquery-core,jquery-migrate,backbone,wp-hooks,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-mouse,wp-api-request&ver=6.6.1:4
on @ load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=underscore,jquery-core,jquery-migrate,backbone,wp-hooks,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-mouse,wp-api-request&ver=6.6.1:4
initPreview @ editor.min.js?ver=3.23.4:3
onStart @ editor.min.js?ver=3.23.4:3
onStart @ editor.min.js?ver=3.23.4:3
(anonymous) @ backbone.marionette.min.js?ver=2.4.5.e1:24
f.triggerMethod @ backbone.marionette.min.js?ver=2.4.5.e1:24
start @ backbone.marionette.min.js?ver=2.4.5.e1:25
(anonymous) @ editor-loader-v2.min.js?ver=3.23.4:2
(anonymous) @ editor-loader-v2.min.js?ver=3.23.4:2

I really cannot figure out what the issue can be. I have another similar install where all core files are the same.
Deactivating, uninstalling, and reinstalling Elementor does not work either, always get back to the same issue.
I have tried disabling and clearing the WordPress cache, but that also does not seem to work.

Have you tried to uninstall other plugins too? and enable only elementor?

Yes, already did that too, same issue.

Try to temporarily switch your theme to a WordPress default theme. This will let you know if the problem is coming from the theme or from Elementor.
